# Add web parts to JSON template sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

Is it possible to add web parts to a JSON template so that when a page is created certain web parts automatically display?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a [Site Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema) when you say JSON template? If so, there is not currently support for configuring webparts on pages.

However, this can be accomplished using [PnP Provisioning called from a site script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning) (or just skip the script and apply your templates directly). You can also do this with [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpclientsidewebpart?view=sharepoint-ps).

Comment: Thanks man that is the answer I was looking for, do you happen to know if a road map has been put out yet for configuring webparts on pages? Everything I read is it is all still in beta.

Comment: It's been discussed a lot. Honestly though, I wouldn't hold my breath when it comes to Site Designs. I would expect to see more investments in areas like the [provisioning service](https://provisioning.sharepointpnp.com/). To be clear, however, I don't work for Microsoft and can't speak on their behalf.