# Is it possible to disable check in/out within a JSON site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

So I am using a JSON template for sharepoint online, is it possible to disable check in/out on all document libraries via the pre-built template? Or would I have script this some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Site Designs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#create-a-new-sharepoint-list) do not currently support enabling or disabling check in/out on lists/document libraries. List creation is fairly limited in terms of settings and is mostly intended to create lists with columns with a few other fancy items like formatting.

Similar to your [previous question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281582/add-web-parts-to-json-template-sharepoint-online), I recommend doing this with **PnP PowerShell**. You could always [call that PowerShell in an Azure Function using Site Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning) but there are added complications and potential costs going that route.

Here is the [PnP PowerShell command to disable check in/out on a library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps). Doing this for all lists/libraries should be relatively straightforward by using the [`Get-PnPList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps) and using a `foreach` on the results.

```
Set-PnPList -Identity "My Library" -ForceCheckout $false
```

Comment: Hey do you or anyone know know have a tutorial on calling the azure functions? I am running into issues with the Microsoft one.